# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - EF Core can't translate GroupBy and Join

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I recently updated my web application and I regret all my most complex requests no longer weigh. I saw that a lot of people had this problem but I don't quite understand how to solve them. I know that other posts talk about that but I don't see how to adapt it to my requests.  I have two types of requests that are problematic:

1st problem (solved):

```
 //error in this part "GroupBy(i => i.CodeMemo).Where(g => g.Count() == 1)"
var MemoMonde = await _context.MemoEmploye.GroupBy(i => i.CodeMemo).Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Select(emp => new
                {

                    emp.CodeMemo,
                    emp.Lu,
                    emp.Actif,
                    Memo = new
                    {
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.Titre,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.Contenu,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.DateEcheance,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.Urgent,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmploye,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeSociete,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.DateCreation,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.ToutLeMonde,
                        emp.CodeMemoNavigation.Supprime,
                        emp.CodeMemo



                    },
                    destinataireE = new
                    {
                        emp.CodeEmployeNavigation.Nom,
                        emp.CodeEmployeNavigation.Prenom,
                        emp.CodeEmployeNavigation.CodeEmploye,
                        emp.CodeEmployeNavigation.Identifiant
                    },
                    employe = emp.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmploye != null
                        ? _context.Employe.Select(soc => new { soc.Nom, soc.Prenom, soc.Identifiant, soc.CodeEmploye }).FirstOrDefault(code =>
                            code.CodeEmploye == emp.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmploye)
                        : null,

                    societe = emp.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeSociete != null
                        ? _context.Societe.Select(soc => new { soc.Nom, soc.CodeSociete }).FirstOrDefault(code =>
                              code.CodeSociete == emp.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeSociete)
                        : null
                    ,
                    photo = _context.MemoFichier.Select(file => new
                    {
                        file.CodeMemo,
                        file.CodeFichier,
                        file.CodeFichierNavigation.Chemin,
                        file.CodeFichierNavigation.Nom
                    }).Where(fi => fi.CodeMemo == emp.CodeMemo).ToList()
                }).Where(t =>
                    t.destinataireE.CodeEmploye == codeEmploye && !t.Memo.Supprime && t.Actif)
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Memo.DateCreation).ToListAsync();
```

Solution to get non-unique value count of table in ef core 3 without GroupBy :

```
var memoSANS = _context.MemoEmploye.Where(x => x.CodeEmploye != codeEmploye).ToList();
var memoSANS1 = memoSANS.Select(x => x.CodeMemo).ToList();
var memoAVEC = _context.MemoEmploye.Where(x => x.CodeEmploye == codeEmploye && !memoSANS1.Contains(x.CodeMemo)).ToList();
var memoAVEC1 = memoAVEC.Select(x => x.CodeMemo).ToList();
and && memoAVEC1.Contains(t.CodeMemo) to the big request
```

and the second problem :

```
var MemoEmp = await _context.MemoEmploye.Select(mr => new
            {
                mr.CodeEmployeNavigation.Identifiant,
                mr.CodeMemo,
                mr.CodeEmployeNavigation.Nom,
                mr.CodeEmployeNavigation.Prenom,
                mr.Lu,
                mr.Actif,
                mr.CodeEmploye,
                Memo = new
                {
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.Titre,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.Contenu,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.DateEcheance,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.Urgent,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmploye,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeSociete,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.DateCreation,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.ToutLeMonde,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.Supprime,

                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeMemo
                },
                destinataireE = mr.CodeMemoNavigation.MemoEmploye.Select(a =>
                    new
                    {
                        a.CodeEmployeNavigation.Nom,
                        a.CodeEmployeNavigation.Prenom,
                        a.CodeEmployeNavigation.Identifiant,
                        a.CodeEmployeNavigation.CodeRole,
                        a.CodeEmployeNavigation.CodeEmploye
                    }).ToList(),
                employe = new
                {
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmployeNavigation.Nom,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmployeNavigation.Prenom,
                    mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeEmployeNavigation.Identifiant
                },
                societe = mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeSociete != null ? _context.Societe.Select(soc => new { soc.Nom, soc.CodeSociete }).FirstOrDefault(code => code.CodeSociete == mr.CodeMemoNavigation.CodeSociete): null
                ,
                photo = _context.MemoFichier.Select(file => new
                {
                    file.CodeMemo,
                    file.CodeFichier,
                    file.CodeFichierNavigation.Chemin,
                    file.CodeFichierNavigation.Nom
                }).Where(fi => fi.CodeMemo == mr.CodeMemo).ToList()
            }).Where(me => me.CodeEmploye == codeEmploye && !me.Memo.Supprime && me.Actif && !MemoMonde.Select(r => r.Memo.CodeMemo).DefaultIfEmpty().Contains(me.Memo.CodeMemo) && !Archi.Select(r => r.Memo.CodeMemo).ToList().Contains(me.Memo.CodeMemo) && me.destinataireE.Count() != 1).ToListAsync();
//error in this part : "!Archi.Select(r => r.Memo.CodeMemo).ToList().Contains(me.Memo.CodeMemo)" & "!MemoMonde.Select(r => r.Memo.CodeMemo).DefaultIfEmpty().Contains(me.Memo.CodeMemo)"
//the error comes from me.destinataireE.Count() != 1 we can't specify condition about a nested request
```

solved : the error comes from me.destinataireE.Count() != 1 we can't specify condition about a nested request

I just spent hours there without results, I desperately seek help thanks in advance

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions already. First of all, you're asking about EF Core. ASP.NET Core is a web framework, not an ORM or data access library.  LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, nor can it convert any call to SQL. EF Core takes a LINQ query and converts it to SQL if possible. Any calls to local methods can't be translated

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? EF Core 3? EF Core 3.1? Which line causes the problem?

Comment: One-liners aren't helpful either. Right now *none* of the queries is visible, only some types. The code that's actually causing the problem needs a lot of scrolling back and forth to read

Comment: You're using queries inside queries inside queries - this is very hard for humans to read, results in bad SQL queries and is probably the reason for the errors too. The *data* model is rarely suitable as a domain model or an API or UI model. That's why you need to map between them. The ORM is the wrong tool for that, it's job is to map between Objects and Relational constructs, not act as a complex mapping tool

Comment: I can't read or format this code and I won't try. Simplify the queries and map the results separately. You can use AutoMapper to reduce (but not eliminate) hand-coded mapping, like mapping similarly named properties, flatten or unflatten objects etc

Comment: Hello, indeed I took a long time to build this in ef core 2.2 but it worked very well. 
In this case, it is better to make several requests rather than to combine everything in one?

Comment: In EF 2.2 it breaks down the queries into multiple queries and they removed it in 3.0. You should extract the queries that use context in your query and assign them separately. (eg, employe, societe and photo)

Comment: @JonathanMoy it probably didn't work in EF Core 2.2 - before EF Core 3.0 SQL support was so limited (especially compared to EF 6) that EF Core would execute on the *client* any operations it couldn't translate to SQL. This was nothing but a stopgap measure. EF Core 1 couldn't even perform a GroupBy. This means EF Core would load a *lot* more data than needed and filter, group, project in-memory. This was a performance killer to say the least

Comment: No, you already had a bug in your query. If you check your application logs, you'll find EF Core warnings about this. What you tried would never work in .NET Framework either. Your code was already slow, already loading a ton of data instead of just the results

Comment: Even if you go back to EF Core 2.2, you still need to fix the bug. And the unmaintainable code - it's not just hard to read or maintain, it's too brittle. Every little change threatens breaking everything

Comment: OK thanks a lot! so i have to redo everything

Comment: Client-side evaluation is [explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#previous-versions) including how to turn it off in EF Core 2.2. Try it to see what happens to your query

Comment: I have been using .net core for 2 years and I did not know that. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post that i bumped into, but let us make something clear. When you use a group by in SQL it wants to use a COUNT, SUM, AVG, ... things like that. Creating a pivot result of objects (if i call this by the right name) is something completely different and cannot be done in SQL. BUT you can create a query with pagination and everything and high performance that actually create a pivot result of objects. I'll share my code here of a query that i once created and tested with 1 milion records and it was still a high performance request. So like in the comments before, your query was already bad from the beginning because you should have seen the warnings where everything is loaded into memory and when you have that in scenarios where you have a giant database your program will go very slow.

"Think out of the box"

```
public async Task<IPage<ITranslationRecord>> GetTranslationRecordsAsync(
        string countryCode,
        string applicationKey,
        bool onlyMissingTranslations,
        string searchItem,
        int pageNumber,
        int pageSize,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "{Repository} {Method} query data for Country {CountryCode} and Application {ApplicationKey}.",
            GetType().Name,
            MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
            countryCode,
            applicationKey);
        pageNumber -= 1;// The user want to see page 1 but we calculate starting on 0

        if (pageNumber < 0) {
            pageNumber = 0;
        }

        IQueryable<Culture> cultures = _globalizationDbContext.Cultures
            .Where(x => x.Name == "en" || x.Country.TwoLetterCode == countryCode);

        int numberOfCultures = await cultures.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

        IQueryable<Translation> cultureResourceTranslations = GetCultureResourceTranslationsQuery(
            cultures,
            _globalizationDbContext.Resources);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchItem)) {
            cultureResourceTranslations = cultureResourceTranslations.Where(x =>
                x.Resource.ResourceApplication.Name.Contains(searchItem) ||
                x.Resource.ResourceSubject.Name.Contains(searchItem) ||
                x.Resource.Key.Contains(searchItem) ||
                (x.ResourceTranslation != null && x.ResourceTranslation.Value.Contains(searchItem)));
        } else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationKey)) {
            cultureResourceTranslations = cultureResourceTranslations.Where(x => x.Resource.ResourceApplication.Name == applicationKey);
        }

        if (onlyMissingTranslations) {
            cultureResourceTranslations = cultureResourceTranslations.Where(x => x.ResourceTranslation == null);
        }

        // This becomes the selected cultures again, empty or not, filtered or not, for every FILTERED resource.
        var resourceTranslations = GetCultureResourceTranslationsQuery(
            cultures,
            cultureResourceTranslations.Select(x => x.Resource))
            .Select(rt => new {
                CultureCode = rt.Culture.Name,
                ResourceApplication = rt.Resource.ResourceApplication.Name,
                ResourceSubject = rt.Resource.ResourceSubject.Name,
                ResourceKey = rt.Resource.Key,
                Parameters = rt.Resource.ResourceExampleParameters.OrderBy(x => x.Index).Select(x => x.Value),
                ModifiedAt = (DateTime?)rt.ResourceTranslation.ModifiedAt,
                Translation = rt.ResourceTranslation.Value
            });

        int numberOfMaximumRecords = (await resourceTranslations.CountAsync(cancellationToken)) / numberOfCultures;
        int numberOfMaximumPages = (numberOfMaximumRecords - (numberOfMaximumRecords % pageSize)) / pageSize;

        if (pageNumber > numberOfMaximumPages) {
            pageNumber = numberOfMaximumPages;
        }

        var result = await resourceTranslations
            .OrderBy(x => x.ResourceApplication)
            .ThenBy(x => x.ResourceSubject)
            .ThenBy(x => x.ResourceKey)
            .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize * numberOfCultures)
            .Take(pageSize * numberOfCultures)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        List<ITranslationRecord> translationRecords = result
            .GroupBy(x => new {
                x.ResourceApplication,
                x.ResourceSubject,
                x.ResourceKey
            })
            .Select(x => new TranslationRecord() {
                ResourceApplication = x.Key.ResourceApplication,
                ProductKey = x.Key.ResourceSubject + '.' + x.Key.ResourceKey,
                Parameters = x.Select(y => y.Parameters).First().ToList(),
                Translations = x
                    .Select(y => new TranslationRecordPair() {
                        CultureCode = y.CultureCode,
                        Translation = y.Translation
                    } as ITranslationRecordPair)
                    .ToList()
            } as ITranslationRecord)
            .ToList();

        return new Page<ITranslationRecord>(pageNumber + 1, numberOfMaximumRecords, numberOfMaximumPages + 1, translationRecords);
    }

    private IQueryable<Translation> GetCultureResourceTranslationsQuery(
        IQueryable<Culture> cultures,
        IQueryable<Resource> resources) {
        var cultureResources =
           from r in resources.Distinct()
           from c in cultures
           select new {
               Resource = r,
               Culture = c
           };

        return from rc in cultureResources
               from rt in _globalizationDbContext.ResourceTranslations
                   .Where(x => x.CultureId == rc.Culture.Id)
                   .Where(x => x.ResourceId == rc.Resource.Id)
                   .DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new Translation {
                   Culture = rc.Culture,
                   Resource = rc.Resource,
                   ResourceTranslation = rt
               };
    }
```